# session variable use in another php page

Tags: php, html

I want to use session variable in another page. I used data which is got from database to store in variable. When I try to use it another page error god undefined  index. Code is below. help me to solve this

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require('dbconnection.php');
    $output='';
    $sql="select * from vacancy";
    $res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $imageno=$_SESSION[$row['vacancyid']];
    ?>
```

other.php page

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <div>
    <?php

    $src='images/vacancy/'.$_SESSION["imageno"].'.jpg';
    echo "<img src='".$src."'>";
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to store `$imageno` in  session variable!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't *setting* a session variable, it's trying to *read* one:

```
$imageno=$_SESSION[$row['vacancyid']];
```

It sounds like you meant to do this instead:

```
$_SESSION["imageno"] = $row['vacancyid'];
```

That is, to read the *database row* and set the value *to* the session.

Answer (score 0):

To get user details for every page you have to include this in your every page

```
   <?php
session_start();
require('dbconnection.php');
$output='';
$sql="select * from vacancy";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
$_SESSION["imageno"] = $row['vacancyid'];
?>
```